# Php Mysqli: How to delete multiple entries in one query

Tags: php, sql

How can I combine these two queries:

```
$deletetix = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM presale WHERE PID = '$codeID'");
$deleteorder = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM oc_customer_ohistory WHERE order_date = '$todaydate'");
```

into one query, so that it's more efficient

Comment: Are these two tables related?  If not, then there is no way to delete from both in a single query.  If you can join them, then tell us what the relationship is.

Comment: what makes two tables related? if there is a foreign key relationship?

Comment: There just needs to be a way to relate the two tables.  Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```